# storing floating point values using parse ios sdk

Tags: parse-platform

Does anyone know what the correct way of storing floating point values in a parse object is?

I have a floating point value :

```
float testValue = 12345.6787f;
```

If I try and store it using ios parse code :

```
parseScore[scoreId] = @(testValue);
```

Then I get 12345.68 stored in the parse backend which oddly enough when I retrieve this value I actually get 12345.6797

I have tried setting this value manually using :

```
parseScore[scoreId] = @12345.6787;
```

and it works fine which suggests that this should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, how many significant digits does float have? Why are you using float in the first place and not double?

Comment: Does the number of significant digits matter? It's a generic floating point number that could be 0.1, 1.0, 1.43, 4345.94533, 3.402823e+38

Comment: I was using floats because that's what I usually do unless I need to store large numbers.

Comment: NSNumber* testNum1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:12345.6787]; parseScore[scoreId] = @12345.6787 - this behaves like the above double assignment.   NSNumber* testNum2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:12345.6787f]; gives me the same result as what I'm seeing. So I guess that explains the difference between the two.